# ASP.Net MVC model binding child list property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I have a controller action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyItem item){
    ...
}
```

My type definitions look like this

```
public class MyItem{
    ...
    public List<MySubItem> MySubItems{ get; set; }
}

public class MySubItem{
    ...
}
```

I have created a custom model binder for `List<MySubItem>` and registered it

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List<MySubItem>), new MySubItemsModelBinder());
```

I was expecting that when the automatic model binder was binding `MyItem` it would use `MySubItemsModelBinder` when it was binding the `List<MySubItem> MySubItems` property of `MyItem` but it does not.

What Im wondering is if my expectation is incorrect or if I have misconfigured somewhere?